# each document contains 3 fields with dates, is it possible to return the documents according to the date closest to today contained in those fields?

Tags: mongodb

I have a database with a structure like this:

```
{
  "bidding":"0ABF3",
  "dates":{
    "expiration_date_registration":ISODate("2020-08-24T23:51:25.000Z"),
    "expiration_date_tender":ISODate("2020-08-23T23:51:25.000Z"),
    "expiration_date_complaints":ISODate("2020-08-22T23:51:25.000Z")
  }
},
{
  "bidding":"0ABF4",
  "dates":{
    "expiration_date_registration":ISODate("2020-08-19T23:51:25.000Z"),
    "expiration_date_tender":ISODate("2020-07-25T23:51:25.000Z"), // this is the closest expiration date with respect to today ("this question was asked on July 24)
    "expiration_date_complaints":ISODate("2020-08-13T23:51:25.000Z")
  }
}
```

I have 3 fields each containing a date. `expiration_date_registration`,`expiration_date_tender`,`expiration_date_complaints`

I would like that when a request is made to my database, it is returned in order of expiration date according to the dates contained in these 3 fields.

In this case the output should show the second document first (in this example it is the field with the date closest to today (this question was asked on July 24), `"expiration_date_tender":ISODate("2020-07-29T25:51:25.000Z")`) and so on, an order using these 3 fields to determine the order in which my documents will be displayed.

it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but not very efficient. Here's an aggregate pipe that calculates the distance from now for each of your dates, then gets and sorts by the min distance.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/HwittyBRjzZ
https://mongoplayground.net/p/EGp20ftjh-P

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      datesArr: [
        "$dates.expiration_date_registration",
        "$dates.expiration_date_tender",
        "$dates.expiration_date_complaints",
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      distances: {
        $map: {
          input: "$datesArr",
          in: {
            $abs: {
              $subtract: [
                "$$NOW",
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      minDist: {
        $min: "$distances"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      closestDate: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            closestDateIndex: {
              $indexOfArray: [
                "$distances",
                "$minDist"
              ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$datesArr",
              "$$closestDateIndex"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      minDist: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: great!! friend, just one last thing, how can I put in each object the date closest to today as it is saved (in the ISO format)? for example in the first object the date closest to today is `expiration_date_registration`  I would like to know how I can return the value of this date in the ISO format as it is saved

Comment: You could simply map the distances to date values with a $switch like this. https://mongoplayground.net/p/HwittyBRjzZ  but it gets a bit unwieldy. So this is a cleaner alternative using array indexes https://mongoplayground.net/p/EGp20ftjh-P

Answer (score 0):

You can use $subtract to find difference between today date ($currentDate) and "expiration_date_tender" and then user $sort to get the desired document on top. You can fetch the top document with collection.findOne() function